# Execute a line of code when the user clicks on the close button in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have this code that tries to kill the wampmanager process when the user press on a button. But how can I achieve the same thing if the user clicks on the close button. Is it possible to execute a small line of code just when the user clicks on the close button?
If you know any alternatives in achieving this, please do tell. thanks

```
  Dim pProcess() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("wampmanager")

            For Each p As Process In pProcess
                p.Kill()
            Next
```

Comment: please help ,If you know how to disable the close button please tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `FormClosing` event for that. You can have a common function and call them in button `Click` and this event.